# Не переведено уведомление при редактировании вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Уведомление после редактирования вопроса не переведено с англ. на русский.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавил пока такие варианты:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14175

   > **Спасибо за предложенную правку**.
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14176

   > Правка будет видна только вам до тех пор, пока не будет одобрена проверенными участниками сообщества

Comment: По-моему, во втором лучше "она", а не "правка" - предложения же подряд идут.

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, так лучше, согласен.